# CSS Flex, column-count test: First item not aligned, top-wise, with its peers. Can't figure out why

Tags: css, flexbox

Result:

I'm trying to create a masonry layout. Almost there, but the fact my first item isn't aligned drives me nuts. It's any first item, doesn't matter which one I put first, it's a bit lower than the others in the first row. Can't understand why.

[image]

my container has what I think is needed like:

```
position: relative;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex start;
```

JSFiddled for your convenience:
https://jsfiddle.net/cxtrqz4v/

Comment: Hi Jason, please provide a [mcve] here in the question rather than only linking to an off-site code sandbox. This will help prevent linkrot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero in on `.parent { margin: 10px }`. When you remove it, the problem goes away. I think there's a margin-collapse or margin-`column-count` issue.

Comment: That did it. I removed the `margin: 10px` from the `parent`, replaced it with `column-gap` on the container. This created a zero vertical spacing between items, i resolved with an explicit `margin-bottom: 10px` item. Thanks. I'll look into `margin collapse` and `margin-column-count` as I wasn't aware of these...

Comment: Sounds good. Glad I could help. By the way, by "margin collapse" and "margin `column-count`", I wasn't referring to any properties. They were just terms to describe concepts possibly related to the problem.

Comment: @JasonGenX setting `display:inline-block` to the elements fix also the issue. It's indeed a margin collapsing issue as each margin-top will collpase with the previous margin-bottom of the previous element and the first one will not collapse with parent because of padding (even without padding it won't collapse, probably column-count disable it)